# Feature not implemented Query: select * from alarm_status Parameters: []

Tags: mysql, jdbc, mule, mule-studio

i try to connect with my JDBC with from mule ESB and this is my code:

```
 <jdbc:mysql-data-source name="MySQL_Data_Source" user="myUsrName" password="myPass" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb" transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="MySQL Data Source"></jdbc:mysql-data-source>
<jdbc:connector name="Database" dataSource-ref="MySQL_Data_Source" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database" ></jdbc:connector>
<flow name="JDBCFlowFlow1" doc:name="JDBCFlowFlow1"> 
    <jdbc:inbound-endpoint queryKey="Q1" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="1000" connector-ref="Database" doc:name="Database"> 
        <jdbc:query key="Q1" value="select * from myTable"></jdbc:query>  

    </jdbc:inbound-endpoint>  
    <logger message="---------------Result: #[payload]------------------------" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger>  
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="path" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"></file:outbound-endpoint>  
</flow>
```

but i get this error

```
ERROR 2014-10-23 09:14:02,860 [[project].Database.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.jdbc.JdbcMessageReceiver: java.sql.SQLException: Feature not implemented Query: select * from myTable Parameters: []
```

how can i solve this probleme?

Answer (score 0):

The same configuration worked on my end, is there data in the table? what version of Mule/jdbc driver did you use?

Comment: this is caused by the version of runtime, this problem is solved by  downloading the version 3.4.1 EE.